# El Capitan bootable installer on Mac Mini - "A required download is missing"

Tags: macos, mac-mini, bootable-disk

On a freshly created USB bootable disk for El Capitan (following [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) which create a USB bootbale installer with `sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app`)

On a Mac Mini 2014 when trying to install El Capitan off the bootable USB

I am getting this message  **"A required download is missing"**

the machine is connected via ethernet to the upstream network

[image]

my hard drive is 500GB and reformatted **Mac OS (Journaled)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably used an old macOS installer app to create your USB bootable disk.

A lot of macOS installer apps downloaded before Oct 2019/Nov 2019 contain an outdated certification chain and thus are invalid.

Simply download a new [OS X El Capitan install.dmg](http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-41424-20191024-218af9ec-cf50-4516-9011-228c78eda3d2/InstallMacOSX.dmg) (with a valid cert chain this time), open the dmg and open the InstallOS.pkg. The installer package installs the "Install OS X El Capitan.app" in the Applications folder.

The app's ressources can be used to create a new installer thumb drive with the well known command:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app
```

Other installers with valid cert chains:

Sierra: [How to upgrade to macOS Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208202) – [Download macOS Sierra](http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-39476-20191023-48f365f4-0015-4c41-9f44-39d3d2aca067/InstallOS.dmg) (direct d/l).
High Sierra: [How to upgrade to macOS High Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208969) – [Get macOS High Sierra](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?ls=1&mt=12) (App Store link)
Mojave: [How to upgrade to macOS Mojave](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210190) – [Get macOS Mojave](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?ls=1&mt=12) (App Store link)

As of recently (**October 2019**) users have [reported](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250793420) a certificate issue that may require the system datetime to be backdated via terminal in the installer.

Comment: I find Signet and Taccy to be invaluable for checking expired certificates on apps and installers. https://eclecticlight.co/taccy-signet-precize-alifix-utiutility-alisma/

Comment: @bmike Excellent link - I visited the site often in the last year but strangely never opened the *Download* link (probably I expected the usual 3rd party suspects...(Onyx...etc.))